# Javascript - Regex for allowing only selected special characters only

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to allow only specific special characters like in a text like `?*=.@#$%!^":,:;<'>+-_`.

I have tried the below code:

```js
pattern = new RegExp(/^(?=.*?[?*=.@#$%!^":,:;<'>+-_])/);
```

It does not seem to work, it seems to pass even if I am entering a special character other than the ones specified above. Am I missing something here?

e.g.:

```
var sampleText: string = "TestSample&123"
```

The above example should throw an error and fail since I have not used any of the special character which is specified in the pattern.

Comment: Can you provide an example?  A quick test in the console and it seemed to work in the way I think you intend for it to...

Comment: @AlexanderNied : I just updated my question

Comment: why it has to be with regex?

Comment: @LeandroBardelli : Because i am using a custom validator in a mat-password-strength which needs a regex pattern.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matching special characters and letters in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946651/matching-special-characters-and-letters-in-regex)

Comment: @LeandroBardelli : no because i need only special characters and that too selected ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the charset you want and [the approach from this answer here about exclusive sets in Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2788763/6831341), you should be able to do something like this:

```js
const testPattern = /^[?*=.@#$%!^":,;<'>+\-_]+$/;

console.log(testPattern.test('?*+@!')); // passes
console.log(testPattern.test('TestSample&123')); // fails
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- Javascript has regex literals, so you can do `var regex = /^(?=.*?[?*=.@#$%!^":,:;<'>+-_])/` instead of `new Regex(...)`
- https://regex101.com/ is a super helpful resource for figuring out regex. Paste `^(?=.*?[?*=.@#$%!^":,:;<'>+-_])` into that site and it'll explain what each part does.
- The `^` at the beginning of the regex anchors the matching to the beginning of the string, but you don't have a corresponding `$` to make sure the match applies to the entire string.
- The `(?=.*?` is a positive lookahead that mathces any number of any character. The character group `[...]` that you have is only going to match a single character, when it sounds like you want it to match *all* of the characters.

Rahul already answered while I was typing this up, and he's got the right expression:

```
^[?*=.@#$%!^":,:;<'>+-_]*$
```

The `^` anchors the match to the beginning of the string, and the `$` anchors the end of the match to the end of the string. The `[...]*` will match any number of characters as long as they belong to that set of characters.

You can make a JS var out this like

```js
var myRegex = /^[?*=.@#$%!^":,:;<'>+-_]*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the below regex:

```js
    const str = /^[a-zA-Z0-9?*=.@#$%!^":,:;<'>+-_]+$/;
    
    console.log(str.test('TestSample&123'));
```

Comment: pattern = new RegExp(^[a-zA-Z0-9?*=.@#$%!^":,:;<'>+-_]+$); like this ???.. This gives me compile time error The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type